# How to disable the ripple effect?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, ripple

I have a layout `ConstraintLayout` which has multiple children, and one child is having the ripple effect

> ```
> (android:foreground="attr/selectableItemBackground")
> ```

and my parent `ConstraintLayout` also have the same ripple effect. My question is how to disable the child item ripple effect if the parent is already having the ripple, or any conditional way we can use to disable ripple.

when I click on parent item it shows both ripple parent as well as children.

```
 <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/investment_pack_item_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:onClick="@{(v) -> handlers.onClick(v, obj)}">

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:id="@+id/logo_iv"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/margin_70dp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/margin_70dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/padding_layout"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/padding_layout"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/padding_layout"
        app:imgUrl="@{obj.imageUrl}"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:placeHolder="@{@drawable/bg_grey_rectangle_rounded_corner}"
        app:shapeType="@{2}"
        tools:src="@tools:sample/avatars" />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/ivp_item_category"
        layout="@layout/ivp_item_category_returns_recycler_item"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/logo_iv"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:obj="@{obj}"
        app:type="@{Constants.OTHER_PACKS}" />

    <android.support.constraint.Barrier
        android:id="@+id/barrier_ivp_1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:barrierDirection="bottom"
        app:constraint_referenced_ids="ivp_item_category,logo_iv" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:id="@+id/logo_icon"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/icon_height_width_xxsmall"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/icon_height_width_xxsmall"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        app:imgUrl="@{obj.createdBy.imageUrl}"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/created_by"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/logo_iv"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/created_by"
        app:placeHolder="@{@drawable/bg_grey_rectangle_rounded_corner}"
        app:shapeType="@{2}"
        tools:src="@tools:sample/avatars" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/created_by"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/padding_layout_8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/padding_layout_8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_4dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/padding_layout"
        android:text="@{obj.createdBy.name}"
        android:textColor="@color/text_color_dark_grey"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_very_small"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/logo_icon"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/risk_image"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/barrier_ivp_1"
        tools:text="Aditya Birla Mutual Fund" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:id="@+id/risk_image"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/margin_16dp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/margin_16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/padding_layout_8dp"
        app:imgSrc="@{RiskView.getRiskImage(obj.riskType.id)}"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/risk_type"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/risk_type"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/risk_type"
        app:placeHolder="@{@drawable/bg_grey_rectangle_rounded_corner}"
        tools:src="@drawable/ic_transaction" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/risk_type"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/padding_layout_8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/padding_layout"
        android:includeFontPadding="false"
        android:text="@{obj.riskType.displayName}"
        android:textColor="@color/text_color_dark_grey"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_very_small"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/logo_icon"
        tools:text="Moderate" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

### **Include layout**

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/lyt_category_returns_item"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="@{!type.equals(Constants.OTHER_PACKS)}"
    android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:onClick="@{(v) -> handlers.onClick(v, obj)}"
    android:padding="@dimen/padding_layout">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/scheme_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawableEnd="@drawable/ic_forward"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_forward"
        android:drawablePadding="@dimen/margin_6dp"
        android:text="@{obj.fundName}"
        android:textColor="@color/text_color_black"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_small"
        tools:text="Aditya Birla Mutual Fund" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/fund_category_2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/padding_4dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner_light_grey_bg"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/padding_layout_8dp"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/padding_4dp"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/padding_layout_8dp"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/padding_4dp"
        android:text="@{obj.fundCategory}"
        android:textColor="@color/text_color_dark_grey"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_xs_small"
        android:visibility="@{obj.fundCategory != null ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/scheme_name"
        tools:visibility="gone" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/minimum_investment_header"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/padding_layout_8dp"
        android:text="@string/minimum_investment"
        android:textColor="@color/text_color_grey"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_very_small"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/category_returns_header"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread_inside"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/fund_category_2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/minimum_investment_value"
        style="@style/currencyTextStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/padding_layout_4dp"
        android:text="@{Apputility.getFormattedPrice(obj.minimumInvestment.doubleValue(), true, 0)}"
        android:textColor="@color/text_color_black"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_small"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/minimum_investment_header"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/minimum_investment_header"
        tools:text="₹ 1000" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/category_returns_header"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@{type.equals(Constants.OTHER_PACKS)?@string/schemes:@string/allocation}"
        android:textColor="@color/text_color_grey"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_very_small"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/returns_header"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/minimum_investment_header"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/minimum_investment_header"
        tools:text="@string/schemes" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/allocation_percentage"
        style="@style/currencyTextStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/padding_4dp"
        android:text="@{type.equals(Constants.OTHER_PACKS)?``+obj.schemeCount:``}"
        android:textColor="@color/text_color_black"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_small"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/category_returns_header"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/category_returns_header"
        tools:text="60"
        tools:visibility="visible" />

    <com.ui.common.CategoryReturnProgressView
        android:id="@+id/category_return_range"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/padding_2dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin_30dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_30dp"
        app:categoryReturn="@{obj.allocation}"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/allocation_percentage"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/allocation_percentage"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/returns_header"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/allocation_percentage"
        app:min="@{obj.allocation}"
        app:visibility="@{!type.equals(Constants.OTHER_PACKS)}"
        tools:visibility="gone" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/returns_header"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@{(obj.bucket != null)?obj.bucket:@string/returns}"
        android:textColor="@color/text_color_grey"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_very_small"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/category_returns_header"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/minimum_investment_header"
        tools:text="Returns"
        tools:visibility="visible" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/returns_value"
        style="@style/currencyTextStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/padding_layout_4dp"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:minEms="3"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_small"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/returns_header"
        app:return="@{obj.returns}"
        app:returnColor="@{obj.returns}"
        tools:text="+36.23%" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: kindly share some code `XML` like what kind of attributes you are using and to be exact what kind of child view we are talking?

Comment: @Muhammadwaris added the XML files which I am using.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use custom style with a transparent color:

```
<style name="noRipple" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents">
    <item name="rippleColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

and set in your view:

```
style="@style/noRipple"
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: OP doesn't want to trigger the child ripple when the parent view is clicked. Doesn't this just makes the child ripple disappear completely?